# Find $7^{1\,000\,000\,000\,000\,000} \bmod{107}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What is a shortcut to doing this kind of problem?  I know that 7 and 107 are both prime number; thus, I assume that has something to do with the appropriate approach/solution.  But beyond that I am not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Since $53$ is a Germain prime it is easy to check that $7$ is a primitive root. Highly improbable this question was assigned without the OP knowing FLT :)

Comment: I don't see how your first sentence is related to the second, @N.S.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Since the order of $7$ is $106$, calculating the powers of $7$ until they repeat is basically undo-able. And I am not familiar with any other trick which would work, and be taught before FLC.

Comment: That assumes it was an assigned problem. Back when I was in grade school, I encountered these sort of problems in a math game, without a class attached. Anyway, the method of repeated squaring reduces it to about 100 multiplications :) @N.S.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint 1:**

Since $107$ is prime 
$$7^{106} \equiv 1 \pmod{107}$$

**Hint 2:**
$$100 \equiv -6 \pmod{106}$$
Hence 
$$1,000,000,000,000,000 \equiv 10 \cdot 100^{7} \equiv 10 \cdot (-6)^7 \pmod{106}$$

This is easy to compute.